# Regex for Ascii only

Tags: regex

I'm trying to develop a regex for password validation that requires the following criteria,

- 1 Uppercase
- 1 Numeric
- 8-45 length
- Ascii only as specified in [OWASP list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_special_characters)

I came up with this lookahead regex but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with non-ascii characters.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=[\x20-\x7E]).{8,45}$
```

Tested on,

```
ABCD1234abcd!" #$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

However, doesn't seem to work with non-ascii characters i.e. it still matches the non-ascii characters despite of `\x20-\x7E`,

```
ABCD1234abcd!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~£
```

Notice that I do want to include the whitespace as well.

Anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You should read [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex allows any character via the dot `.`. Your look ahead only required the *first* character to be ascii.

Change the dot to your ascii range:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[\x20-\x7E]{8,45}$
```